# Is there an advantage in declaring "this" on every reference to itself in a script in C#?

Tags: c#, this

I'm looking at code from another programmer and style differences aside, they do something I don't.

On every single reference to the class' own variables and methods, they precede it with `this`. (ie. `this.Init()` x `Init()` )

On my side, I've mostly used `this` to pass a reference to the instance to other classes, or, on occasion, when I needed to differentiate from `base`.

Is there any particular advantage in explicitly referring to `this` every time?

Comment: It's helpful if you're getting paid by the number of characters you type.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: It might be nice for Intellisense to pick up faster on class-internals -but I despise it ;)

Comment: if requirements change forcing you to refactor a method and make it run in several threads at the same time, `this.ClassObject` let's you spot those land mines that can be overseen easily but cause problems at runtime where you can spend a lot of time searching for the reason...

Comment: StyleCop's default configuration requires `this` be specified on all internal member references.  It's super annoying, but some people insist on following StyleCop religiously, without really thinking things through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No functional difference.  Perhaps the project coding style guidelines require it, in which case you should use it.